# Calibre fails to install

Tags: pdf, ssl, calibre

When trying to install Calibre, the PDF converter, on Linux using the instructions from this page:

http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux

I get this error:

```
# python linux-installer.py
Installing to /opt/calibre
Downloading tarball signature securely...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linux-installer.py", line 669, in <module>
    main()
  File "linux-installer.py", line 648, in main
    download_and_extract(destdir)
  File "linux-installer.py", line 620, in download_and_extract
    get_tarball_info()
  File "linux-installer.py", line 612, in get_tarball_info
    ('x86_64' if is64bit else 'i686'))
  File "linux-installer.py", line 576, in get_https_resource_securely
    c.connect()  # This is needed for proxy connections
  File "linux-installer.py", line 500, in connect
    self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, ca_certs=self.cert_file, ssl_version=self.calibre_ssl_version)
  File "/export/home/jm43436/build/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 387, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/export/home/jm43436/build/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 143, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/export/home/jm43436/build/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 305, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:507: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

I tried the --no-check-certificate approach, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down on that page, the first bullet point:

```
sudo -v &&
    wget --no-check-certificate -nv -O- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/master/setup/linux-installer.py |
    sudo python -c "import sys; main=lambda:sys.stderr.write('Download failed\n'); exec(sys.stdin.read()); main()"
```